# Resetting List to new quantity of objects

Tags: c#, list, grasshopper, rhino3d

I'm having a problem with an accumulation of Point3ds in List. When I change the number of int agents (via a gui slider in grasshopper) the quantity keeps increasing rather than resetting to whatever the new quantity should be. I'm guessing that somewhere I should be re-initializing the list or clearing it everytime the value is changed? What would be the correct to do this?

```
        protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
        {
            BoundingBox box = new BoundingBox(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, boundx, boundy, boundz);
            DA.SetData("Bounding Box", box);
            DA.SetData("Start", "The current trigger is set to " + started.ToString());

            // Initialize Agents
            for (int i = 0; i < agents; i++)
            {
                double xPos = RandomfromDouble(0.0, boundx);
                double yPos = RandomfromDouble(0.0, boundy);
                double zPos = RandomfromDouble(0.0, boundz);

                Point3d pos = new Point3d(xPos, yPos, zPos);        // Create Agent Start Position
                Vector3d vec = new Vector3d(xPos + RandomfromDouble(-360.00, 360.00), yPos + RandomfromDouble(-360.00, 360.00), zPos + RandomfromDouble(-360.00, 360.00));  // Create Agent Start Vector

                Agent agent = new Agent(pos, vec, alignment, separation, cohesion, neighborRadius);
                allAgents.Add(agent);

                DA.SetData("Debug", "# of Agents Created: " + allAgents.Count);
            }

            // Get agent positions
            List<Point3d> agentPositions = new List<Point3d>();
            List<Vector3d> agentVectors = new List<Vector3d>();

            agentPositions = allAgents.Select(agent => agent.Pos).ToList();
            agentVectors = allAgents.Select(agent => agent.Vec).ToList();

            DA.SetData("Agent Count", allAgents.Count);
            DA.SetDataList("Agent Points", agentPositions);
            DA.SetDataList("Agent Vectors", agentVectors);

            if (started)
            {
                DA.SetData("Start", "The current trigger is set to " + started.ToString());

                for (int i = 0; i < generations; i++)
                {
                    DA.SetData("Debug", "# of Generations: " + i);

                    foreach (Agent agent in allAgents)
                    {
                        DA.SetData("Debug", "# of Agents: " + i);

                        agent.UpdateAgent(allAgents);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (!started)
            {
                DA.SetData("Start", "The current trigger is set to " + started.ToString());
                //return;
            }
        }

        public double RandomfromDouble(double from, double to)
        {
            double diff = Math.Abs(from - to);
            return rnd.NextDouble() * diff + from ;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your code correctly, your issue is that the `allAgents` list keeps getting longer. As you guessed, that's because you're creating the list once, at the top, and then you only ever add to it, within the `for` loop that says `// Initialize Agents`.

If your intent is to reset the list at this point, then before you enter the `for` loop I think you need to do `allAgents.Clear()`. This will empty the list, and then you loop through and add the new `Agent`s within the loop.

Comment: thank you, i've edited my posted code to be more concise.

Comment: Also just realized that Moving List<Agent> allAgents = new List<Agent>(); back into SolveInstance function, for the for loop also fixes the issue.

Comment: You can put that line into `SolveInstance()` as long as that `allAgents` doesn't need to be referenced from outside that method. If it does, then you need to create the list where you had it before, and just clear it inside of `SolveInstance()`.